# Python 3: Opening A Magnet Link Contained In A Variable

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, bittorrent, utorrent

I have a magnet link (e.g.: *magnet:?xt=urn:btih:1c1b9f5a3b6f19d8dbcbab5d5a43a6585e4a7db6*) contained in a variable as a string and would like the script to open the default program that handles magnet links so that it starts downloading the torrent (like if I opened a magnet link from within my file manager).

For the sake of making answers clear we will say that we have the magnet link in a variable called `magnet_link`.

Comment: I am on Windows myself, but if you could give me the command(s) for Mac and Linux also and then I can use _os.name_ or some equivalent to find the operating system so that the right command can be used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows you can use [`os.startfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
os.startfile(magnet_link)
```

For Mac/OSX you could probably use applescript and pipe it to `osascript`, for Linux you might be able to use `xdg-open`.

Comment: I get the following error:

`WindowsError: [Error -2147217406] Windows Error 0x%X: 'magent:?xt=urn:btich:1c1b9f5a3b6f19d8dbcbab5d5a43a6585e4a7db6'`

Comment: Which OS? Are you sure you have an application associated with the magnet protocol?

Comment: This is on Windows 7 - I'm pretty sure that I have uTorrent associated with the magnet protocol, but how could I check this?

Comment: For completeness: On Linux, you can probably call the `xdg-open` command with it.

Comment: @EdenCrow Interestingly the magnet link in your question does seem to throw that error for me, however a real magnet link seems to work fine. I haven't tested extensively, though.

Comment: @zeekay Could you give an example of a "real" magnet link? The one I put in the question is a real magnet link and should result to some Ubuntu installation. Is there some information I haven't included/should include? The problem may be in the way I have generated the magnet link itself rather than the solution you have provided.

Comment: For instance consider this magnet link for OpenOffice: `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:bb372b915a4b057b58264847e56407f7a531f369&dn=OpenOffice+3.1.1+%28Language+Pack+Only%29+Linux+%28x86%29+English+%28en-GB%29&tr=http://borft.student.utwente.nl:6969/announce`

Comment: @EdenCrow: Try `magnet:...` instead of `magent:...`

Comment: Also it should be `magnet:?xt=urn:btih` not `btich`.

Comment: AndiDog: Thanks - it's always the little typos that are the worst!
@zeekay That works. Thanks.

Comment: how to exactly use the xdg-open for ubuntu to open magnet links?

Answer (score 3):

#### Here is a small code snippet that sums up the method on all the operating systems

```
  import sys , subprocess
  def open_magnet(magnet):
        """Open magnet according to os."""
        if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
            subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', magnet],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
            os.startfile(magnet)
        elif sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
            os.startfile(magnet)
        elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
            subprocess.Popen(['open', magnet],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        else:
            subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', magnet],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the mac, if you have an installed app that will handle it, just pass the link to the open command

```
open "some url"
```

Using something from subprocess i would imagine

Comment: Thinking more, the open command will let you specify an application too.